# How to use Execute Javascript keyword in robot framework for clicking an element

Tags: javascript, selenium, robotframework

I need to click a button whose xpath is "**//input[contains(@value,'Export to Excel')]**" through **Execute Javascript** keyword. I don't know how to use it.

Can anyone help me out!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it as below

```
Execute JavaScript    document.evaluate("ur xpath",document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code it is working fine. I have a doubt. In my code after executing the Javascript executer I will execute an autoit script to handle a window popup. After executing the Autoit script only a single line of code present after the autoit script is executing and remaining codes are not executing. I don't know why. Can you help with this??

Comment: Thats wierd cause i am using it and it works perfectly fine. Try focussing the window and then try again

Comment: I tried with that also but it was not working for me. While debugging this code I tried with page reload, after page reload I was able to perform remaining actions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found out for this problem is I have **reloaded the page** after **executing the AutoIT** script, then I was able to execute the remaining code.